# Usar un ciclo en bash con cat

Tags: bash

Estoy utilizando `cat` en ***bash*** para unir varios archivos en uno solo, como son mas de mil carpetas no deseo hacer una instrucción para cada carpeta, como puedo hacer un ciclo para que pueda recorrer todas las carpetas y se unan los archivos de las respectivas carpetas.

Lo que hago para unir los archivos es el siguiente código:

```
cat /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8/2014322/2014322_0b8*.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8/2014322/2014322_0b8.msd

cat /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8/2014323/2014323_0b8*.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8/2014323/2014323_0b8.msd

cat /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8/2014324/2014324_0b8*.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8/2014324/2014324_0b8.msd
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes que nada, tu pregunta es demasiado genérica, deberías tratar de granularla más, por ejemplo podrías preguntar como listar los carpetas que están en una ubicación particular pero no a menor ni a mayor profundiad.

Para responder a tu duda, lo que puedes hacer es, listar las carpetas que están dentro de la carpeta `/media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8` y procesar la salida dentro de un ciclo, por ejemplo:

```
find /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do echo $d; done
```

Lo que ves en la salida, es la ruta completa a cada una de las carpeta que encontraste. Entonces puedes usar el comando basename para pasar a una variable el nombre de la carpeta de la siguiente forma:

```
find /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); echo $dname; done
```

Esto debería darte el nombre de la carpeta sin toda la ruta. Entonces puedes usar las dos variables que tienes para ejecutar el comando `cat` que mencionas en la pregunta:

```
find /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"_0b8*.msd > cat "$d/$dname"_0b8.msd ; done
```

puedes depurar el script en una línea usando la instrucción `set -x` y desactivar la depuración usando el comando `set +x` y también puedes usarlo de la siguiente forma antes de ejecutar la versión final:

```
find /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); echo cat "$d/$dname"_0b8*.msd ">" cat "$d/$dname"_0b8.msd ; done
```

Solo tendrías que remover el echo cuando ya veas que los comandos que se ejecutan en el ciclo while son correctos

Comment: Gracias por la observación tratare de indagar mas en mis próximas preguntas. Respecto a tu respuesta estoy poniendo en practica lo que explicaste pero a la hora de correr el script me aparece lo siguiente: _Las rutas deben preceder la expresion: /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/0b8_ uso:  find [-H] [-L] [-P]

Comment: Es un warning, no tengo forma de probarlo. Editaré el post :D

Comment: ya probe como dijiste, y lo corre sin errores. Y cuando hace el cat no lo hace del todo bien osea segun une los archivos pero hace archivos de 0bytes en realidad no los une solo los crea, por que pasa eso?

Comment: @Armando probablemente no está encontrando los archivos. Revisa si tengo los nombre de archivo y de carpetas bien escritos, revisa la salida del comando find sin el while, ejecuta los comandos previos al final y también puedes activar la depuracón con el comando `set -x` antes de realizar la prueba. El último  ejemplo que te pasé, tenía un error, si quieres ver qué comandos se ejecutarían, corre la última versión. Deberías líneas iguales a los comandos que pones como ejemplo.

Comment: Ya pude solucionar lo que dices, ahora lo que pasa es que tengo un conflicto con una carpeta que a su vez tiene otras subcarpetas con varios dias asi mira
 _/media/user/PENDRIVE/test/Mate/2015126/b900/1/archivos1.msd
 /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/Mate/2015126/b900/9/archivos9.msd 
 /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/Mate/2015127/b900/1/archivos1.msd
 /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/Mate/2015127/b900/9/archivos1.msd_

Comment: Intente con este codigo, pero no funciono. Alguna sugerencia?
 
`find /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/Mate/*/*/1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*.msd > "$dname"_mate_b900_1.msd ; done 

 find /media/user/PENDRIVE/test/Mate/*/*/9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*.msd > "$dname"_mate_b900_9.msd ; done`

Comment: Si tienes dificultades no esperadas, esto amerita una nueva pregunta. Formula una nueva pregunta con un ejemplo de las carpetas que quieres procesar y de las que no deberías procesar ignorar. Recuerda proveer tanto detalle como sea posible. Te sugiero que compartas la salida parcial del comando `find /media/user/PENDRIVE/test` En contexto, podría sugerirte que hicieras un find sin los parámetros mindepth y maxdepth y luego filtraras por grep, pero es poco útil para la comunidad que estemos 'chateando' sobre tu problema en los comentarios